# T-Sql multiple self-Joins to return single main value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, inner-join, self-join

If I have a table like below

```
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
-----------------------------
|  A   |  B   | *null* | *null* |
| *null* |  B   |  C   | *null* |
| *null* | *null* |  C   |   D  |
```

And I have a stored proc that can take in four parameters like so

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Testing]
    @value1 varchar(1) = NULL,
    @value2 varchar(1) = NULL,
    @value3 varchar(1) = NULL,
    @value4 varchar(1) = NULL
```

If only single one value is passed in at a time I would like to get the value A from COL1
e.g. If @value4 is passed with the value 'D' in then I would like to get A by self joining row 3 D so we can get C which gets row2 C gets use B which gets row1 which gets us A
Currently I do something like (witten by hand so might not fully run) this

```
DECALRE @use varchar(1)
IF(@Value1 IS NOT NULL OR @Value2 IS NOT NULL)
    SELECT TOP 1 @Use = COL1 FROM TAB t1 
    WHERE COL1 = @Value1 or COL2 = @Value2
ELSE IF (@Value3 IS NOT NULL)
    SELECT TOP 1 @Use = COL1 FROM TAB t1 
    INNER JOIN TAB t2 ON t1.COL2 = t2.COL2
    WHERE COL3 = @Value3
ELSE IF (@Value4)
    SELECT TOP 1 @Use = COL1 FROM TAB t1 
    INNER JOIN TAB t2 ON t1.COL2 = t2.COL2
    INNER JOIN TAB t3 ON t2.COL3 = t3.COL3
    WHERE COL4 = @Value2
```

This works but is there a way to make this shorter?
I am using sql server 2012

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Are the empty spaces in the table at the top NULLs or values you don't care about for this query?

Comment: The empty spaces represent nulls. Sorry that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3, t3.col4
FROM tab t1
JOIN tab t2 ON t1.col2 = t2.col2
JOIN tab t3 ON t2.col3 = t3.col3
WHERE 
  COALESCE( @Value1, t1.col1 ) = t1.col1 AND 
  COALESCE( @Value2, t2.col2 ) = t2.col2 AND 
  COALESCE( @Value3, t3.col3 ) = t3.col3 AND 
  COALESCE( @Value4, t3.col4 ) = t3.col4  
GROUP BY t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3, t3.col4
```